# Aggregation in Hibernate / JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

Let's say I have an entity such as

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_entity")
Entity {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "id")
   int id;

   @Column(name = "name")
   String name;

   @Column(name = "version")
   int version;

   @Column(name = "parameter")
   String parameter;
}
```

Now, I need to fetch latest versions of entities having given names and specific parameter value. In plain SQL I'd write something like this:

```sql
select id, name, max(version) version, parameter
from entity 
where name in ('foo', 'bar') and parameter = 'baz'
group by name, id
```

But, how do I do that with Hibernate (preferably using Criteria API) ?

UPD:

First of all, as it was stated in comments, my example query is incorrect. The correct version of what I was trying to achieve looks more like this:

```sql
select e0.id, e0.name, e0.version, e0.parameter from entity e0 
right join (select name, max(version) mv from entity where name in ('foo', 'bar') group by name) e1 
on e0.name = e1.name and e0.versioin = e1.mv
where e0.parameter = 'baz'
```

My best working version so far involves two separate requests:

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = sessionFactory.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Tuple> lvq = cb.createQuery(Tuple.class);
Root<Entity> lvr = lvq.from(Entity.class);

lvq.multiselect(lvr.get("name").alias("name"), cb.max(lvr.get("version")).alias("mv"));
lvq.where(lvr.get("name").in("foo", "bar"));
lvq.groupBy(lvr.get("name"));

List<Tuple> lv = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(lvq).getResultList();

CriteriaQuery<Entity> cq = cb.createQuery(Entity.class);
Root<Entity> root = cq.from(Entity.class);

List<Predicate> lvp = new LinkedList<>();
for (Tuple tuple : lv) {
    lvp.add(cb.and(
        cb.equal(root.get("version"), tuple.get("mv")),
        cb.equal(root.get("name"), tuple.get("name"))));
}

cq.select(root).where(cb.and(
        cb.equal(root.get("parameter"),"baz"), 
        cb.or(lvp.toArray(new Predicate[lvp.size()])));

return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Btw, probably I was not clear enough about which Criteria API I wanna use, so it's JPA.

Thank you guys for answers, they've pushed forward to create ugly, but at least working solution.
I will appreciate any suggestions how to improve the code for such a task.

Comment: First correct your SQL query before asking to get the equivalent in criteria query; I don't think you can aggregate on an ID field.

Comment: yes, you're right - this query is incorrect, it came from the top of my head just for this example

Answer (score 0):

```
createCriteria(Entity.class).add(Restrictions.in("name", new String[] {"foo","bar"})).add(Restrictions.eq("parameter","baz")).add( Projections.groupProperty("name")).add(Projections.groupProperty("id")).list()
```

Something like this should work. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Entity.class,"entity");
criteria
.add(Restrictions.in("name", new String[] {"foo","bar"}))
.add(Restrictions.eq("parameter","baz"))
.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
.add(Projections.property("name"), "name")
.add(Projections.property("id"), "id")
.add(Projections.max("version"))
.add(Projections.groupProperty("name"))
.add(Projections.groupProperty("id"))
.list();
```

I hope this works